# / and * in C++ money class implementation

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, numbers

Money.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Money {
private:
    long pounds;
    int pence;

public:
    Money();
    // Overloaded constructors
    explicit Money(long pounds);
    Money(long pounds, int pence);

    /* Overload operators to allow easier arithmetic of money objects, we will
     not overload * or / as it does not make logical sense for money to be multiplied
     or divided.
    */
    Money operator+(const Money& moneyRhs) const;
    Money operator-(const Money& moneyRhs) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Money& money);

    // toString method to print out money object
    std::string toString() const;

    // Getters
    long getPounds() const;
    int getPence() const;
};
```

Money.cpp

```
#include "Money.h"
#include <iomanip>

Money::Money(): pounds(0), pence(0) {}

Money::Money(const long pounds): pounds(pounds), pence(0) {}

Money::Money(const long pounds, const int pence): pounds(pounds), pence(pence) {}

Money Money::operator+(const Money& moneyRhs) const {
    // Convert all money to pence then do addition
    const long poundsInPence = (pounds + moneyRhs.pounds) * 100;
    const int totalPence = pence + moneyRhs.pence;
    const long allPence = poundsInPence + totalPence;

    const Money m3 = Money(allPence / 100, allPence % 100);
    return m3;
}

Money Money::operator-(const Money& moneyRhs) const {
    // Convert all money to pence then do subtraction
    const long poundsInPence = (pounds - moneyRhs.pounds) * 100;
    const int totalPence = pence - moneyRhs.pence;
    const long allPence = poundsInPence + totalPence;

    const Money m3 = Money(allPence / 100, allPence % 100);
    return m3;
}

std::string Money::toString() const {
    std::string strMoneyFormat;

    // Check so see if the pence value is 1 digit, if so we need to add a trailing 0 for output
    // e.g £150.5 becomes £150.05
    if((getPence() > 0 ? static_cast<int>(log10(static_cast<double>(getPence()))) + 1 : 1) < 2) {
        strMoneyFormat = std::to_string(getPounds()) + "." + "0" + std::to_string(getPence());
    }
    else {
        strMoneyFormat = std::to_string(getPounds()) + "." + std::to_string(getPence());
    }

    return strMoneyFormat;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Money& money) {
    os << money.toString();
    return os;
}

long Money::getPounds() const {
    return pounds;
}

int Money::getPence() const {
    return pence;
}
```

I have the above money class implementation for a basic UK banking app, however, I know in coding, in general, it's best practice if you overload one type of operator e.g arithmetic you should overload its others as well, so here I have overloaded the + and -, so I need to overload / and *. However, it doesn't make much sense to multiply or divide the money, is there a way i can go about overloading these to operators that anyone knows, that would make sense?

Update:

```
template <class T>
    Money operator*(T number) const {
        const int penceMult = pence * number;
        const int newPence = penceMult % 100;

        const long newPounds = pounds * number + (penceMult / 100);
        Money tmp(newPounds, newPence);
        return tmp;
    }

    template <class T>
    Money operator/(T number) const {
        if (number == 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Division by zero");
        }

        long total = (100 * pounds) + pence;
        const long result = total / number;

        const int newPence = result % 100;
        const long newPounds = result / 100;
        Money tmp(newPounds, newPence);
        return tmp;
    }
```

Comment: You should overload the others _if they make sens for your application_. If they don't, don't.

Comment: "_it doesn't make much sense to multiply or divide the money_" - No, not with `Money` but with a integer or floating point variable, it would make sense.

Comment: Dividing money by money could make sense, but the return type wouldn't be `Money`, but more likely `double`.  If I have £50.36, and coffee costs £21.42 per kilo, how much coffee can I buy?

Comment: @NateEldredge I see does my multiply operator overload look fine?

Comment: For integer multipliers, yes.  For floating point, no.  If I have £3.00 in the bank earning 10% interest, and I want to know how much I will have next year, I might do `Money(3,0) * 1.1`.  That would compile with your code, but would return £3.00 instead of the correct £3.30.

Comment: I think you might also have problems if the multiplier or divisor is negative.  Actually I think you have problems with negative money in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s reason by analogy here. Suppose I have a type representing a vector in 4D space. I can add and subtract such vectors, but there isn’t a meaningful way to multiply those vectors together (I mean, there is the dot product, but that doesn’t produce a vector). So even though I might overload the + and - operators for my type, I wouldn’t implement * or / on two vectors. (I might overload * and / for a vector and a scalar though, since that’s mathematically meaningful.) I also wouldn’t overload %.

Similarly, suppose I have a type representing a string. It makes sense to overload + and += there, but I haven’t a clue what - or -= means for strings, nor what * or / should do.

And finally, suppose I have a type representing an immutable quantity. Then I might implement + and - and * and / on it, but I wouldn’t implement +=, -=, *=, or /= on that type.

All this is to say that the advice of “if you overload one operator, you should also overload related ones” doesn’t ring true to me. It’s worthwhile if you overload one operator to ask whether there are other related operators also worth overloading (+= if you’ve overloaded +, for example), but that doesn’t mean you should add overloads for operators that aren’t intrinsically meaningful just to “round out” a set of operators.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, however i still decided to provide a implementation (added to question) do you think it looks fine?

Comment: That’s a separate question from the one you initially asked. It’s probably a better fit for our Code Review site, since that’s a bit more subjective.